# Redirecting a web app from localhost:8080/my-webapp to localhost with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a web app hosted by tomcat that I can see on `localhost:8080/my-webapp/`. I would like to redirect it to `localhost` with apache, but am unable to do so.

Here is my configuration file for apache:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache works, but when I go to `localhost` I am getting the default "it works" html file (not my web app) - I restarted apache multiple times.

Is there a standard way to do the redirection?

Note: I am using Apache 2.2.22 on Debian.

EDIT: `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log` after I restart Apache:

```
[Thu Oct 09 09:52:33 2014] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Oct 09 09:52:33 2014] [warn] module deflate_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Oct 09 09:52:33 2014] [warn] module proxy_html_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Oct 09 09:52:33 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.37       proxy_html/3.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: 1. are there any other config files? Do you have entries in your error.log file?

Comment: @John 1. no other config file (except apache.conf). 2. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the comments: First scrap the first three lines. Then try the following:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
 ServerName localhost

 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/

 LogLevel debug
 CustomLog /var/log/apache/localhost.proxy.access.log combined
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache/localhost.proxy.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Then check the config using `apache2ctl -t` and reload apache if everything's fine.

In case apache still serves the default web site, use `apache2ctl -S`to see a list of all loaded VirtualHosts. Also, append the contents of the newly created localhost.proxy.error/access.log in the post.